# Fixed background in a lightSlider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've created this lightSlider with a backgrund image. The problem is that when u go to next slide a new image with the same background image appear. i want the background image to be fixed, so that it is only the text or content which slide.

http://jsfiddle.net/2patspw2/515/

html code:

```
<div class="demo">
    <ul id="demo" class="content-slider">

        <li>
            <div class="slider-content">
                <h3>1</h3>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="slider-content"><h3>2</h3></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="slider-content"><h3>3</h3></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="slider-content"><h3>4</h3></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="slider-content"><h3>5</h3></div>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
    ul{
        list-style: none outside none;
        padding-left: 0;


    }
    .content-slider li{

        text-align: center;
        color: #FFF;
        background:url('http://tnuqq21kt870t8n1egkbrmbr.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/MLG-Championship-Anaheim-2014-Crowd-Enrique-Espinoza.jpg') no-repeat;background-size: cover;

    }

    .content-slider {

    }

    .content-slider .slider-content {
        margin: 0;
         padding: 60px 20px;

    }
    .demo{

          position: relative;
           overflow: hidden;
        width: 300px;


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add background in the demo class like,

```
.demo {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    background:url('http://tnuqq21kt870t8n1egkbrmbr.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/MLG-Championship-Anaheim-2014-Crowd-Enrique-Espinoza.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/2patspw2/521/)

Also, if you want the bullets background as white then add below property in your stylesheet,

```
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSpg{
    background:#FFF; // use !important in case of overwrite
}
```

[Another demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/2patspw2/527/)